# Where can I find a service hosting tournaments with prize funds?

Tags: multiplayer, community-management, tournament

I have a game, and users are self-organizing to create tournament sites. They want to be able to create a tournament, have competitors put down a $1 each, and the winner takes all.

Are there any companies that provide a service like this that I could integrate into my game directly? Or do people usually build this themselves into their games? I don't really want to deal with maintaining escrow accounts and all that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and I urge you to go get advice from one.

If people can get money out of it you're dealing with various **gambling laws** here and this is on-line so you're dealing with multiple jurisdictions as well.

This is a legal labyrinth I would stay clear of unless you have the financial means to get a bunch of lawyers specialized in this stuff.

**This is one reason why things like in-game trading cards are auctioned for service credits and the money never goes back into the player's hands**.

In many jurisdictions players receiving physical prizes can also count as gambling when a purchase is necessary.

There are also other risks that arise when going into gambling services, not just legal ones.

Comment: Playing games of skill has always been legal in the United States and is not classified as gambling. A site that offers these types of games has a statement here, including legal references: http://www.gamecolony.com/no_gambling.html

Comment: The United States aren't the entire world and nowhere does it say user76683 is in the USA.

Comment: While true, games of skill are classified differently than games of chance irrespective of country simply *because* a player can be better than the House.